# How is the upper bound for Normalized Mutual Information determined?

Tags: clustering, entropy, information-theory, mutual-information

Mutual information between two clusterings $A$ and $B$ can be calculated as:

$$MI(A,B)=H(A)+H(B)-H(A,B)$$

In the [10th page of this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.06508.pdf) it is stated that $MI(A,B)$ can vary in the range $[0,\min\{H(A),H(B)\}]$ (I'm not sure why, though). Therefore, to take the mutual information to the normalized range of $[0,1]$, it should be divided by one of the following upper bounds:

$$\min\{H(A),H(B)\}\leq \sqrt{H(A)H(B)} \leq \frac{H(A)+H(B)}{2} \leq\max\{H(A),H(B)\}$$

I've seen in `sklearn`'s implementation that [the third one is used](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#id11), while for example in R's package `aricode` [the default is the fourth one](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/aricode/aricode.pdf). I personally think that the only one that makes sense is the first one, as it is the actual maximum value $MI(A,B)$ can return.

Which one should be chosen? Why isn't the first bound used everytime if it is the actual maximum value of $MI(A,B)$ according to that paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debate on appropriate normalization for mutual information is a long one.  Each normalization has trade-offs, and everybody has their preferences.  So I can't really answer your first question of: which one should be chosen.  Personally, I don't like any of the mutual information measures for clustering comparisons, and prefer some other measures as discussed in [Gates et al (2018)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.06136).

To answer your second question, the true bound of $min\{H(X),H(Y)\}$ is rarely used because it can equal 1 even if the clusterings X and Y are not identical.  This occurs when one clustering places each element in its own cluster.

Here is a quick example using the [CluSim package](https://github.com/Hoosier-Clusters/clusim):

```
from clusim.clustering import Clustering, print_clustering
from clusim.sim import nmi

c1 = Clustering(elm2clu_dict = {0:[0], 1:[1], 2:[2]})
c2 = Clustering(elm2clu_dict = {0:[0], 1:[1], 2:[1]})
print_clustering(c1)
0|1|2
print_clustering(c2)
0|12
nmi(c1, c2, norm_type = 'min')
1.0
```

See [Kvalseth (1987)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4309069) for some of the earliest opinions on the debate of mutual information normalization.

Also, the choice of $max \{H(X), H(Y)\}$ is sometimes used because it is the only normalization which makes 1-NMI a metric on the lattice of partitions, but it has its own sensitivity issues.